# what are the API's in CAPL script?

Tags: capl, canoe, canalyzer

Is there any API to extract the write window of canalyzer automatically through CAPL script or Diagnostic and XCP window?
I know it can be extracted manually but i dont want to extract manually
Thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log Write Output to File in CAPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204029/log-write-output-to-file-in-capl)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a way. Please try the following: go to the `Write` window; in the icon horizontal menu, look for the Configuration icon (rightmost one). It should open a `CANalyzer Options` window. Under `Windows / Blocks > Write Window` look for `Record Messages in a File`. Check `Record Messages` and input a file name and location in the field below the check. It logs your measurement in that file and you can write over it at each measurement start.

It should provide you with an alternative to the manual export of the `Write` window. Please refer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204029/log-write-output-to-file-in-capl) I've marked for further information on how to do it through code. Relevant part of that answer is the usage of `writeToLogEx()` function, which I don't possess in my Vector version. However, I shall point you towards `writeLineEx()`:

> Writes the text into a new line of the specified window, into a page
>   of the CANalyzer Write Window or into a logging file.

AFAIK these are the only options you are given.